# How to register order of checkboxes in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I currently have a list of checkboxes in my webapp. I want to show the order in which the checkboxes have been checked. So I wrote the code below.

```
$scope.updateNumbers = function(id, checked, inputs) {
    if (checked === true) {
        $scope.count += 1;
        var span = angular.element('#'+id+'-'+id);
        span.html($scope.count);
    } else {
        if ($scope.count != 0) {
            $scope.count -= 1;
        }

        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
            var input = inputs[index];

            var span = angular.element('#'+test.id+'-'+test.id);
            if (span.html() > $scope.count || span.html() == $scope.count) {
                span.html(span.html()-1);
            }
        }

        var span = angular.element('#'+id+'-'+id);
        span.html($scope.count);
    }
}
```

And this HTML

```
<div class="list-view__body__row" ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants">
    <div class="list-view__body__cell">
        <input type="checkbox" id="<% restaurant.id %>" value="" 
          class="input-field__checkbox--input" 
          ng-model="restaurant.checked" 
          ng-change="updateNumbers(restaurant.id, restaurant.checked, restaurants)">
        <label for="<% restaurant.id %>" 
          class="input-field__checkbox--label" 
          ng-bind-html="restaurant.name|html"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="list-view__body__cell">
        <div class="order__wrapper" ng-show="restaurant.checked">
            <span id="<% restaurant.id %>-<% restaurant.id %>">0</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the current implementation, though, sometimes the number will go down to 0 or numbers will appear twice. It's not working correctly, so how can I improve on this code?

Comment: shouldn't need to manipulate the dom yourself to do any of this. Use your data model to drive the angular view

Comment: When you check a checkbox, change the order of the data in your case the restaurants, sorting would help if you have a number field in your object that can be changed to 1 when it is checked and sort it

Answer (score 0):

With angular you always want your data model to drive the view. Note that the following solution requires no dom manipulation code and angular manages the dom based on the data. It also requires very little code.

All you need for this is an array of the checked restaurants in your data model.

Then the order is determined by the index within this array and the count is the length of the array.

Controller:

```
  // array to store selections
  $scope.checkedItems=[];

  $scope.updateSelections = function(rest){        
    if(rest.checked){
      // add to array if item is checked
      $scope.checkedItems.push(rest)
    }else{
      // remove from array if not checked
      $scope.checkedItems.splice($scope.checkedItems.indexOf(rest),1)
    }
  }
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="restaurant in restaurants">
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="restaurant.checked" 
             ng-change="updateSelections(restaurant)">
      <label ng-bind="restaurant.name"></label>
    </div>        
    <div ng-show="restaurant.checked">
        <!--   Use index to display order -->
        Order: <span>{{checkedItems.indexOf(restaurant) +1}}</span>
    </div>        
  </div>

  <h3>Count of checked items: {{checkedItems.length}}</h3>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UN5q953JYAkO2oIz6FT8?p=preview)**</kbd>